# Bacterium fixed nitrogen transfer mechanism

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, nitrogen-cycle

As it is well known, Rhizobium and other bacteria have the capacity to fix Nitrogen and thus perform a crucial role in the natrual nitrogen cycle.

I am trying to find a reliable source on how the origin of the nitrogen that the bacteria fix, for example inside the nodules.
Most sources simply explain how nitrogenase converts N2 (in gaseous form) to NH3. But I have not found a source explaining the origins of N2 in the soil environment.

I don't see how the N2 could be diffused in the soil from the atmosphere (it would need impractical large time for such diffusion, and morever that would negate the soil aeration in general)

An agronomist pinpointed the N2 relased in the soil during decomposition, but that N2 would not be a net general fixation (from the atmosphere to the soil as a biological useful nitrogen)

The solubility of N2 into water could explain some net transfer on atmosphereic N2 into the soil, but it is relatively small amount (20mg/L)

So my question is where does the N2 in a plants root environment comes from?

Do the plants transfer N2 to the roots dissolved in the phloem?

I would appreciate and insight and/or any sources.

Comment: related to your question,your bacteria replaces the ammonia step in this cycle  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen_cycle

Comment: What sort of structure do you think soil has? Is it a solid mass like a lump of plastic or metal, or does it have pores/holes/granular structure?

Comment: air contains 78% nitrogen(N2),bacteria converts this to nitrate that the plants can use.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soil_gas

Comment: Thanx for all the comments. The answer to my question seems obvious now. My assumption on the diffusion time is not correct, due to the pore structure of the soil.